# How can I merge a branch without closing the issue in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using Gitlab.

I created an issue and then used the "create branch" button in the issue view page.

I worked on the branch and completed and committed around 80% of work.

When I created a merge request from this branch to master and accepted it, the issue was closed automatically.

What was I supposed to do to accept the merge request without closing the issue?

Or maybe it's a git concept that you should merge a branch only when the issue is complete resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gitlab analyses the commit messages of all commits on the default branch, which is most of the time the master branch.

If it detects an [issue pattern](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/automatic_issue_closing.html), e.g. `fixed #<issue number>`, in a commit message, it will close this issue. Git handles also merges with commits, to be more specific by default it will create a merge commit.

Now to the merge request:

If you create a merge request in Gitlab from such kind of specific issue branch, it will automatically fill the commit message with a reference to the source issue. 
To prevent this you have to delete the commit message before merging.

[image: Merge Request Approval]

See the link on the right side which reads `Modify Commit Message`, there you will find the pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to tell GitLab not to automatically add the "Closes #123" message?  In our workflow issues shouldn't be closed until there's a final manual check in production.

Comment: You can manually remove the reference or change the auto-close regex. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/issue_closing_pattern.html

Comment: @secustor sadly that option is only available in the self-hosted version, not the SAAS version

Comment: @mlncn I have the same issue.  when I approve an MR, the issue is by no means closed.  lots of other things have to happen before it gets closed.  this is really annoying

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it by setting it like this

[image: follow this image]

Uncheck the checkbox

> Auto-close referenced issues on the default branch